# How are damages for landlord harassment calculated?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, damages, harassment, civil-damages

Apparently there are various bases for establishing landlord harassment. Section 28’s method in the housing act 1988 applies where it has caused the occupier to give up occupation. But what if it hasn’t successfully caused the occupier to give up occupation, but only disturbed their peace and comfort therein?

Are tenants not entitled to damages for acts and communications that are reasonably likely to cause them to give up occupation, and if so, how are these calculated?

Comment: Also check out the [Protection from Eviction Act 1977](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1977/43), which covers harassment.